# MvvmCross: Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

I get this error in my binding:

> Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type

This ahppen on this line of code:

```
bindings.Bind(userNameTextView).For(x => x.Layer.BorderColor).To(x => x.LoginError).OneWay();".
```

Here is my code

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using Foundation;
using UIKit;
using CoreGraphics;
using Cirrious.MvvmCross.Touch.Views;
using MvvmCross_POC.Shared.ViewModels;
using Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.BindingContext;
using MvvmCross_POC.iOS.Converters;
using System.Linq;

namespace MvvmCross_POC.iOS.Views
{
    public partial class LoginViewController : MvxViewController
    {
        private UITextView userNameTextView;
        private UITextView passwordTextView;
        private UIButton loginButton;

        public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad();

            this.Title = "login";

            this.View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White;

            var loginView = new UIView(){
                Frame = new RectangleF((float)this.View.Bounds.Width / 4, (float)this.View.Bounds.Height / 4, (float)this.View.Bounds.Width / 2, (float)this.View.Bounds.Height / 2)
            };

            userNameTextView = new UITextView()
            {
                Frame = new RectangleF(0, 0, (float)loginView.Bounds.Width, 30),
                AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth
            };
            userNameTextView.Layer.BorderColor = UIColor.LightGray.CGColor;
            userNameTextView.Layer.BorderWidth = 1;
            userNameTextView.Layer.CornerRadius = 5;

            passwordTextView = new UITextView()
            {
                Frame = new RectangleF(0, 50, (float)loginView.Bounds.Width, 30),
                SecureTextEntry = true,
                AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth
            };
            passwordTextView.Layer.BorderColor = UIColor.LightGray.CGColor;
            passwordTextView.Layer.BorderWidth = 1;
            passwordTextView.Layer.CornerRadius = 5;

            loginButton = new UIButton() {
                Frame = new RectangleF((float)(loginView.Bounds.Width / 2) - 50, 100, 100, 30)
            };
            loginButton.SetTitle("Login", UIControlState.Normal);

            loginView.AddSubviews(userNameTextView, passwordTextView, loginButton);

            this.View.AddSubview(loginView);

            var bindings = this.CreateBindingSet<LoginViewController, LoginViewModel>();
            bindings.Bind(userNameTextView).For(x => x.Text).To(x => x.UserName);
            bindings.Bind(userNameTextView).For(x => x.Layer.BorderColor).To(x => x.LoginError).WithConversion(new BooleanToCGColorConverter());
            bindings.Bind(passwordTextView).For(x => x.Text).To(x => x.Password);
            bindings.Bind(loginButton).For("TouchUpInside").To(x => x.LoginCommand);
            bindings.Apply();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried something like... bindings.Bind(userNameTextView.Layer).For(x => x.BorderColor).To(.....)?  Also if that doesn't work please post your converter code and any stack trace errors.  Also you don't typically new up your converter there.  You should register it in your setup and do something like .WithConversion("BooleanToCGColor")

Comment: I suggest that you split your one line fluent-style call into separate lines to see on which call your problem happen. `var bind = bindings.Bind(userNameTextView);` `var for = bind.For(x => x.Text);` and so on...

Comment: Ok, I fixed it, I had to do 2 things, first I needed to add the System.Linq using statement and the items I was binding to must have a getters and a setter, that was not the case. When I solved this it worked.